# C# Windows Forms - Updating toolStripLabel text returns auto-scrollable panel to top

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, toolstripitem

I have the following form set up:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuwCP.png
(I can't post images due to this account being new)

Whenever I update the text of the underlined ToolStripLabel the scrollbar returns to top, as shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yZu3.png

This is the code which edits the ToolStripLabel.Text:

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, EventArgs e)//requests data
{
    try
    {
        if (commTool != null)
        {
            pollTimer.Stop();
            commTool.Poll();
            writeRequests(commTool.PollCount.ToString());
            if (!stopTimer)
            {
                pollTimer.Start();
            }
            if (errorRate < 0.25)
            {
                setColour(Color.Green);
            }
            else if (errorRate > 0.25 && errorRate < 0.5)
            {
                setColour(Color.GreenYellow);
            }
            else if (errorRate > 0.5 && errorRate < 0.75)
            {
                setColour(Color.Yellow);
            }
            else
            {
                setColour(Color.Red);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error MainMenu.cs, OnTimedEvent(): commTool = null");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error MainMenu.cs, OnTimedEvent(): " + ex.ToString());
    }
}

public void writeRequests(string pollCount)
{
    requests = commTool.PollCount;
    if (statusBar.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(writeRequests);
        Invoke(d, new object[] { pollCount });
    }
    else
    {
        tsLblRequests.Text = "Requests: " + pollCount;
    }
}
```

Any advice or solutions are much appreciated.

Comment: Could you add .NET Framework version and Document Outline screenshot? (while designing the form go to View -> Other Windows -> Document Outline)

Comment: .NET Framework version: 4.6.01055
Document Outline: http://i.imgur.com/IHKYNiD.png
(pnlRoomSettings.Controls are copied to Panel1 and Panel1.AutoScroll is set to true)

Comment: I created a form with scrollable Panel and ToolStrip with ToolStripLabel under the Panel, but updating ToolStripLabel text (even from another thread) doesn't affect scroll-bar at all. Could you make a minimal reproducible example and upload it somewhere?

Comment: I forgot to mention there is a checkbox at the top-right corner of the panel, I removed its contents due to confidentiality. When this checkbox has its CheckedChanged, this problem occurs.
I can reproduce this example later on if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added checkbox and now I can reproduce this behaviour as well. First I thought that it happens because checkbox got focused when check state changed and, of course, panel will automatically scroll to show the focused control. But then I discovered that it will only scroll if I changed ToolStripLabel text as well, without checking `InvokeRequired` property.

I see that you already invoking when changing text of tsLblRequests, but might be there is some other labels, which are requiring invoke. I think that might be the case.

If it's not the case, then you can try to adjust scroll position to show specific control with `panel1.ScrollControlIntoView(label1)`.

If `ScrollControlIntoView` method is not flexible enough, then might be `VScrollBar` control will work better for you.